# jenkins will auto delete workspace's code and then re-pull the code to build each time

Tags: jenkins

I use maven plugin to build my project. Every time I build,
the Jenkins workspace is deleted.

I set it up with the "*Use 'svn update' as much as possible*" check-out strategy.

The question is: Why does it delete my code and not update it?

Is there something I'm missing in my setup?

[image: screenshot of Jenkins config]

System environment:

- centos7
- svn version 1.7
- jenkins version 2.107

Comment: Have you checked `Delete workspace before build starts` in your Build Environment?

Comment: @Sagar i am sure not select "Delete workspace before build starts"

Comment: Are there any post -build actions which delete the workspace?

Comment: no post- build ,i use command "watch -n 1 du -sh /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy-test/ " and the dir will emty when i build  ,i also use iptraf-ng to watch network change . it will re pull the entire code not "svn update"

Comment: @Sagar is jenkins issue ?https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11993

Comment: This might helpful to you. Not a solution though. [https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3580](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3580)

Comment: @Sagar I know the problem,I add port in url,"svn info" != url ,I remove the port 3690 and it work

Comment: Great! Put this as answer so that others can benefit too!